# ALTER TABLE with PDO and parameters?

Tags: mysql, pdo

Is it possible to add parameters with `ALTER TABLE` with PDO.

I have tried,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("ALTER TABLE emblems ADD ? TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', ADD ? DATETIME NOT NULL");
$q -> execute(array($emblemDB, $emblemDB . 'Date'));
```

But it failed.

Thanks.

Comment: since it failed, it's not possible.

Comment: @TheJumpingFrog since I have asked many questions on stack overflow that have failed in testing, every single one of them has been answered.

Answer (score 1):

The nature of alter table queries, to my knowledge are not prepared statements.  But you should call the `beginTransaction` and `commit()` functions for most table altering queries.

```
$dbh->beginTransaction();

/* Change the database schema and data */
$sth = $dbh->exec("DROP TABLE fruit");
$sth = $dbh->exec("UPDATE dessert
SET name = 'hamburger'");
$sth = $dbh->exec("ALTER TABLE `dessert` ADD `field1` VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL");


/* Commit changes */
$dbh->commit();
```

Although you could use the prepared statments and execute as far as I know.

***NOTE:***
MySQL implicitly calls the commit() function on `CREATE TABLE` and `DROP TABLE` queries, so rollback is not possible.

Also, if you're wanting to pass variables to an alter table query, make sure to sanitize your user input (if that's where it's coming from), and create a stored procedure on your db, then call it using PDO and attach your variables for inout.  Just a thought in regards to how your question was worded.

Comment: There is no point in opening a transaction when doing DDL in MySQL given the implicit commit.  In fact, it's outright bad advice to even *pretend* that it could work.

Comment: This answer is so confused ans self-contradicting that it's a real shame for the site.